Transition probability density of non-intersecting Brownian bridges are independent of h function from Doob-h transform?
I've been trying to derive the transition probability of a $2$-dimensional Brownian motion $B = (B^{(1)}_{t}, B^{(2)}_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ conditioned to stay in the Weyl chamber and also conditioned to be a bridge starting in $0$ at time $-T$ and ending in $0$ at time $T$ (i.e. $B^{(2)} > B^{(1)} \  \forall t \in (-T, T)$ and $B_{-T} = B_{T} = 0$).
In a stochastic analysis lecture we derived the transition density for $B$ conditioned to stay in the Weyl chamber $(p^{h}_{t}(x,y))$ via Doob's h-transform (with the function $h(x) = x_2 - x_1$), and it has the following form:
$$
p^{h}_t(x, y) = \frac{h(y)}{h(x)}f_{t}(x,y), \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
where $f_{t}(x,y)$ is some function with exponential terms, but it's not really important for the question.
From this, to get to the density of the process with the bridge conditions $(p^{h,b}((s,x), (t,y))$ (I am also unsure whether this would be time-homogeneous or not, but again not really relevant for the question) I would consider the following limit:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{p^{h}_{s+T}((0,\epsilon), (x_1, x_2))p^{h}_{t-s}((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2))p^{h}_{T-t}((y_1, y_2), (0, \epsilon))}{p^{h}_{2T}((0,\epsilon), (0, \epsilon))}.
$$
But in this fraction all the $h$ functions cancel, which seems weird, because it feels like the original Doob's h-transform disappeared.
Have I made a mistake, or does the $h$ function really disappear, and if so, why would that make sense? I've demonstrated my question on this example, but as far as I know the stucture in equation (\ref{eq1}) is more general, and it seems like in all of those cases the $h$ function would cancel, when doing this bridge conditioning fraction, regardless of what the function is.
